# How to conditionalize nested stack creation via CommaDelimitedList parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, nested-stack

in my AWS CloudFormation Template, I would like to conditionalize nested stack creation via a CommaDelimitedList parameter.

I would have done it this way:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Parameters": {
    "DeployNestedStacks": {
      "Description": "List of nested stack resources to deploy",
      "Type": "CommaDelimitedList",
      "AllowedValues": [
        "nestedStack1",
        "nestedStack2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Conditions": {
    "DeployNestedStack1": { "Fn::Contains": [ { "Ref": "DeployNestedStacks" } , "nestedStack1" ] }
    "DeployNestedStack2": { "Fn::Contains": [ { "Ref": "DeployNestedStacks" } , "nestedStack2" ] }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "MyNestedStack1": {
      "Condition": "DeployNestedStack1",
      "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
      ... 
    },
    "MyNestedStack2": {
      "Condition": "DeployNestedStack2",
      "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
      ... 
    }
  }
}
```

unfortunately Fn::Contains is not a valide Fn.

Still, I think it illustrates well what I would like to achieve.

How would you achieve this, please?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is **no such functionality** in plain CloudFormation (CFN). CFN is not a programming language and it does not have loops, searches though lists and many other things found in regular programming language.

However, there some **possible alternatives** to consider:

- Use of [macros](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html)
- Use of [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html)
- Using [CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/), instead of CFN.
- Redesigning your template to have Conditions based on regular parameter values, not lists. For example using [Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-select.html) to do index based comparison.